# How to add an Exchange Server with AutoDiscover SCP disabled or hidden by default

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange, exchange-2019

I'm building some new Exchange 2019 servers in my environment and do not want clients to immediately use their AutoDiscover service connection points (SCP) that get created in Active Directory during installation. We should be able to update the default InternalUrl/ExternalUrl values and test before these become active. What is the best way to hide, block, or disable the default SCP until I am ready to use them?

Our options appear to be:

- Update the URL values as quickly as possible after the installation completes.

Or run a looping script that looks for the creation of the SCP during installation, and performs an action immediately, such as:

- Remove "Domain Users" read permissions when it is found (or add a 'deny', but 'deny' ACEs...).
- Set the `AutoDiscoverSiteScope` attribute to a non-existent AD site as quickly as possible after the installation completes so the new one is not considered authoritative for an AD site.
- Set the `IsOutOfService` attribute to **$true**.

Or something else to make them start out in a 'disabled' or 'out of service' state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Exchange Team Blog ([Exchange Active Directory Deployment Site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-active-directory-deployment-site/ba-p/604329)), Microsoft recommend creating a deployment site in Active Directory.

Basically, when Outlook searches AD for the list of SCPs, it will look at the keywords attribute for each one; in particular, "Site=MySite" gets a priority of 1, no "Site=" value gets a priority of 2, and "Site=OtherSite" gets a priority of 3. (I'm using MySite and OtherSite as placeholders for actual site names.)

So, as long as you have an existing SCP which matches your clients' site (priority 1), you can add a new SCP for a different site (priority 3) and Outlook will ignore it. That gives you time to configure the new Exchange server before end users actually connect to it, and therefore they won't get certificate warnings etc.

So, you can set up a small subnet (using AD Sites and Services) and put the new Exchange servers in there temporarily. However, note that you will need to have a domain controller in that site. If that's not practical, the only other option is what joyceshen suggested, i.e. do this out of hours and try to update the URI as quickly as possible, but that will cause some disruption.

After you move the new Exchange server to the real site, you will need to update the AutoDiscoverSiteScope property of the client access service:

```
Set-ClientAccessService -Identity "MyServer" -AutoDiscoverSiteScope "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that SCP only works for internal access. If the client search for SCP failed, then it will try the two URLs to try to connect to the Autodiscover service and etc(http redirect, SRV...) You could refer to the official document here which introduces Autodiscover in detail: [Autodiscover service in Exchange Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?view=exchserver-2019)

So, if you don't want outlook clients use SCP, you could try setting the AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri to $null. In addition, we could not set IsOutOfService directly. Command and parameters here: [Set-ClientAccessService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-clientaccessservice?view=exchange-ps)

We could also try using Windows Registry to meet the need disable Autodiscover SCP lookup . Then use GPO to make it take effect on all clients in your domain.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office<Office_Version>\Outlook\AutoDiscover]

Right click on empty space in the Right pane New select "DWord Value". Name the new Dword as ExcludeScpLookup now double click on the newly created DWord to edit its value, set Value to 1 and then click OK.

Here is the link provides step-by-step guide: [Disable Autodiscover SCP Lookup using Windows Registry](https://www.mustbegeek.com/disable-autodiscover-scp-lookup-using-windows-registry/#.X7xk72j7SUk)  (Note: It's not recommended to modify the ADSIEdit by Microsoft)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve what I was asking for. Setting the Uri to $null _would_ help, but the problem is that in the few minutes during the installation process between the default value being set and then the EMS or EAC actually being available to change it--some clients inevitably hit the SCP and try to use that server. Even worse, I've had Exchange installs partially fail in the past, which resulted in the AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri being set, but the partially failed installation resulted in ECP and EMS both being broken and unable to change the value.

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling AutoDiscover on all clients is not an option in our environment.